# Document.write being cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, document.write

I am using a script before page load to write some html into my page with `doucment.write` now this gets cached like crazy only a hard refresh seems to update it.

Now before everyone goes "OMG DONT USE DOCUMNNT.WRIT" I will be getting rid of it but for the moment I need a quick fix.

So is there a way I can force this script to update everytime the page changes (note that it IS called everytime the page changes on multiple pages)

Code is generated on the fly but generally:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="NAV.js"></script>
```

Generated code:

```
d = new dTree('d');
d.add(4,0,'Maps');
d.add(5,4,'Web Map','WebMap.html');
document.write(d);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Are you sure caching is to blame? Doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a dummy parameter in your script tag... you can handle it from your server side language... and it will look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="NAV.js?dummyParameter=546757657657"></script>
```

Also this code in your head tag will help you:

```
<META http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```